# Нужна помощь в написании функции, принимающую произвольное число переменных. Каждая переменная - количество треугольников у елки

Tags: python, изображения

Пример файла для **plantForest(2)**:

```
  *   
 ***  
  *   
 ***  
*****
```

Пример файла для **plantForest(2, 1, 3)**:

```
             *    
            ***   
             *    
            ***   
  *        *****  
 ***         *    
  *         ***   
 ***   *   *****  
***** *** *******
```

Comment: Пожалуйста, уточните вашу конкретную проблему или приведите более подробную информацию о том, что именно вам нужно. В текущем виде сложно понять, что именно вы спрашиваете.

Answer (score 0):

Для того, чтобы функция могла принимать произвольное число аргументов, используйте `*` перед обозначением аргумента функции:

```
def plantForest(*args):
    for i in args:
        ...
```

Comment: Гланая проюлема в том, что я не могу понять как записать "елки" в одним ряд, а не друг под другом. Просто print(..., end=" ") не помогает